# How can I delete an entire list item by clicking a button placed within it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a to-do list application. I want to delete items by clicking a button attached to the list element, but it only deletes the button and not the entire element. Currently, `<li>` elements in a `<ul>` by the following:

```
function newElement() {
    event.preventDefault(); // stop default redirect

    var li = document.createElement("li"); // create an <li> element

    /* make a text node from the input and put it in the <li> */
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("task").value; // retrieve value of text box
    var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue); // create a text node of the box value
    li.appendChild(t); // put the text node in the single <li>

    /* attach a button to the <li> element that deletes it */
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // Create a <button> element
    btn.innerHTML = "X"; // Insert text
    btn.className = "button" // add class name for CSS targeting
    btn.addEventListener('click', removeItem); // add event listener for item deletion

    li.appendChild(btn); // Append <button> to <li> 

    li.addEventListener('click', checkToggle); // add event listener for a click to toggle a strikethrough

    appendItem("list", li); //append the li item to the ul
}
```

and the function called by the button's listener appears as:

```
function removeItem() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
```

I want the button to delete the entire `<li>` node, but it only deletes the button portion of it.

Comment: Please include your html file

Comment: simply `btn.addEventListener('click', function () {li.remove() })` or `this.parentNode.remove()`

Comment: If you use jQuery a great, easy way to do this is to use the `.closest()` method - it looks for the closest parent that matches the query string. In your case `$('#myButton').closest('li')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at this, I think you need to add another parentNode. It seems you are only removing the button right now.

Comment: Oops, didn't see the one above. I'm new to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Just move this one step further up the hierarchy

```
function removeItem() {
    this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) so you are not dealing withe child element references

```
function removeItem() {
  this.parentNode.remove()
  // this.closest('li').remove()
}
```

or since you have a reference, just delete it

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function () { li.remove() })
```